# How can I print the average of the lines in this file?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program in Java which iterates over each line of a text file, this text file contains numbers which are on a separate line, I have successfully made the program read each line and print them to a new file.

However I'm trying to print the average of these numbers to the new file as well, I understand that I would have to treat each line as a float or double (as I'm using decimal numbers) but I'm unsure of how to do this, this is what I've got so far.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
public class Run {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Write(); //call Write method
}

public static void Write() throws Exception {
    String line, lineCut;
    BufferedReader br = null;  //initialise BR- reads text from file
    BufferedWriter bw = null;  //initialise BR- writes text to file
    try
    {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/jbloggs/Documents/input.txt")); //input file
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/Users/jbloggs/Desktop/output.txt"));   //output file

        line = br.readLine(); // declare string equal to each line
        while(line != null) { // iterate over each line 

            lineCut = line.replaceAll(";" , ","); // replace ; with ,

            //lineCut = line.substring(1, line.length());
            //int mynewLine = Integer.parseInt(lineCut);

            bw.write(lineCut); // write each line to output file
            bw.write("\n");    // print each line on a new line
            line = br.readLine();
        }

        System.out.println("success"); //print if program works
        br.close();
        bw.close();
        }

    catch(Exception e){
        throw(e); // throw exception
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: see Double.parseDouble(String) or Float.parseFloat(String)

Comment: Please provide an example of the input. Does each line contain a single number? (Not sure why you are doing the `.replaceAll` in such a case). Conceptually, get the line into a position where you have tokens for each element on the line. Use `Double.parseDouble` or similar to get the numeric value. Add it to an accumulator. Calculate the mean.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not tested. I am considering each line has a number and nothing else. Remember your should check the valou on linecount to avoid an Exception during the conversion from String to float.

```
public static void Write() throws Exception {
    String line, lineCut;
    BufferedReader br = null;  //initialise BR- reads text from file
    BufferedWriter bw = null;  //initialise BR- writes text to file
    try
    {
        br = new BufferedReader(new       FileReader("/Users/jbloggs/Documents/input.txt")); //input file
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/Users/jbloggs/Desktop/output.txt"));   //output file

        line = br.readLine(); // declare string equal to each line
        float sum = 0;
        int counter = 0;  

        while(line != null) { // iterate over each line 

            lineCut = line.replaceAll(";" , ",");  
            sum += Float.parseFloat(lineCut);
            counter++;

            bw.write(lineCut); // write each line to output file
            bw.write("\n");    // print each line on a new line
            line = br.readLine();
        }

        bw.write("Average = ");  
        bw.write(sum / counter);
        bw.write("\n");

        System.out.println("success"); //print if program works
        br.close();
        bw.close();
    }

    catch(Exception e){
        throw(e); // throw exception
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This helped alot in getting to the final solution, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is what you are doing

- reading lines from a file
- replacing ';' with a ','
- writing this modified line to a new file

So in each of above operation, you have never treated the line to be a `Number`. To find average, you need to parse each line of number into real `Number`, `Double.parseDouble("21.2")` etc, and in each iteration, you know what to do :-)
For example:

```
double sum= 0;
int count = 0;
while(line != null) { // iterate over each line 

    lineCut = line.replaceAll(";" , ","); // replace ; with ,

    //lineCut = line.substring(1, line.length());
    int num = Double.parseDouble(lineCut);
    sum = sum + num; count++;
    bw.write(lineCut); // write each line to output file
    bw.write("\n");    // print each line on a new line
    line = br.readLine();
}

br.write(String.valueOf(sum/count));
```